# Any acts_as_commentable_with_threading examples?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and currently i'm trying to create a simple blog platform. I want to implement a commenting functionality with [acts_as_commentable_with_threading](https://github.com/elight/acts_as_commentable_with_threading) gem. I'm not quite familiar with nesting a forms but here is my attempt:

**comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_spot

  # GET /comments/new
  def new
    @comment = Comment.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end

  private
    def get_spot
      @spot = Spot.find(params[:spot_id])
    end    
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
  ... form elements ...
<% end %>
```

but it gives me `undefined method 'comments_path'` error. I'm sure i'm doing it in extremely wrong way cause i'm bit confused with `2.x` and `3.x` examples but i would be really thankfull if you'll point me to some good examples, better gem or simply write me how it should be done :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have set up the routes for comments controller.

```
# routes.rb
...
resources :comments
...
```

Update:

The routes are nested under posts, based on the comment below. In this case, you will get a route like "#{RAILS_ROOT}/posts/1/comments" to which you can (http) POST a comment. However, your form is trying to POST to "#{RAILS_ROOT}/comments", hence the error. In this case, you need to add a form builder in posts/show.html.erb:

```
<p>
  <b>Name:</b>
  <%= @post.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Title:</b>
  <%= @post.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Content:</b>
  <%= @post.content %>
</p>

<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

See [Rails getting started guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) from where this code is extracted.

Comment: according your update: it describes a situation when i have just a regular nested form and posts/comments with one_to_many relationship. When i've tried to use it with this comments Gem, i was getting `unknown method 'comments'`, it was caused by the fact that the Posts model has not any relationship with comments model set up. When i'm adding a `has_many :comments` in Post model i'm getting a different error but i somehow feel that it's not a proper way to use this Comments gem (cause i'm allready declaring acts_as_commentable) and there is nothing said about adding has_many to my model.

Comment: Your routes are incompatible with your form. If you have the nested routes as you described, then the update I posted above is the way to generate the form (not directly create the form). You can create the form like you mention, but then the route should be just resources :comments, and you need to pass in the required parameters manually. Comments are always nested under commentable (Post in this case). If you have acts_as_commentable_threading in the Post model, you don't need to add any comment related association.

Comment: Yeah, i have `acts_as_commentable` in my `Posts` model. When i add this form code (from your answer and from rails getting started guide) to my `views/posts/show.html.erb`, i'm getting `unknown method 'comments' for #<Post:0xb6ea9b04>`, it sounds like rails doesn't know that `Posts` are associated with `Comments`...

Comment: [Per this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917444/how-to-use-acts-as-commentable-with-threading-in-rails): did you create your own comment model?

Comment: Hmm as far as i remember, this Gem created one and i was not generating my own `Comment` model. So i'm using the one that comes with a Gem all the time

Comment: Could you host your whole project somewhere and send a link?

Comment: i'm really thankfull that you're trying to help me so gladly:) if there is any option to reward for answer a bit more than by clicking  'accepted', i'll do so for sure! you just want to check out the code or you need a working copy ? (i can send you the files but i can't send you the layout, that's the one small problem)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10636/discussion-between-mbajur-and-anand)